# Angular: I am unable to set header for http post call

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to set header from http post call, But When I am consoling it to the log, It is printing undefined.

I tried the same for params also, but it is not getting set.

```
callAddGroupAPI(formId, data){
    const headers = new Headers()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log(headers);
}
```

I am expecting output in the console to log the value of headers, But it is print undefined.

I have also tried

```
callAddGroupAPI(formId, data){
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    console.log(headers);
}
```

And this also is not working...

I am getting the same problem when I am using

```
const data = new FormData();
data.set('key', 'value')
console.log(data)
```

I have use .append() also, But that also is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use headers try this,

```
// define in your service.ts constructor
this.httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRFToken': csrf }),
};

// use 
this.http.post(yoururl, payload, this.httpOptions);
```

About formdata, when you do `console.log()` it'll just print`FormData {}`, to access the `key` do `data.getAll('key')` or use `data.forEach`

Answer (score 3):

This is an example how you set header in post request

```
create(custom: CustomObject): Observable<CustomObject> {
    const header = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(custom), { headers: header })....}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};
```

And httpOptions pass in as parameter in your post request

```
myRequest (item: Item): Observable<Item> {
  return this.http.post<Item>(yourUrl, item, httpOptions)
}
```